# How can I get the last match in regular extracor expression in jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, post-processing

I would like to extract the last occurence of regular expression in Jmeter.
I used Regular Extractor expression to do this, but I can't got the last occurence.

I tried this :

- **Regular expression**: "var1":([^"]+),"var2"
- **Template** : $1$
- **Match No** :   -1
- **Default value** : expression_matchNr

Then in my script I used *${expression}* variable

I've tested **expression_matchNr** but it give me the number of match.

What should I put in "**Match No:**" ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could we get an example plz to better understand what you want ?

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a MCVE ( **a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code** ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & **to show your will to respect** other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: cos rants like that^ make the place so much friendlier..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the following output:

```
expression=foo
expression_1=foo    
expression_2=bar
expression_3=**what you looking for**
expression_matchNr=3
```

You can use JMeter's [__V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function to get value of `expression_3` variable

As per function's [description](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V):

For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:

- `${A1}` - works OK
- `${A${N}}` - does not work (nested variable reference)
- `${__V(A${N})}` - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

So in your case the function, returning last match no matter how many matches are will look like:

```
${__V(expression_${expression_matchNr})}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series on what else can be done with functions.

Comment: Thanks, I used ${__V(expression_${expression_matchNr})} variable

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the JMeter core does not support the -1,-2... for ultimate/penultimate etc. notation. You can however find the ultimate occurrence using a *negative look-ahead*

I stumbled on this problem and for me I solved it using something like this:

```
[\s\S]*("var1":([^\"]+),"var2")(?!$1$)
```

and **Template**: $2$

explanation:
match anything until (..1..)-happens where it is not possible to match (..1..) after. 
Return (..2..)

Also the first occurrence of the item:

```
 ("var1":([^\"]+),"var2")(?!$1$)[\s\S]*
```

As for efficiency, this saves the entire query [\s\S]* in a variable, so it is a bit heavy and I haven't tested if it pulls too much memory
If it does, consider using javaScript or JQuery which does support *last* object methods