# Regular Expression Jmeter, making rightmost match according to left boundry value

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I am trying to do correlation in Jmeter using regular expression. 
My scenario is:

> GUID=1232, awsdqdwe click1 ,GUID=21232 berttt click2, b, GUID=323223,babsjbcjhbcc click3

Here I wish to catch GUID of click 3 value which is in numerical ignore all the alphabetical texts 
Regular expression : `GUID=(.*?)(?#text)click3`

But this regular expression takes the leftmost GUID . How do I make it look for first GUID from rightmost boundry match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the last match in regular extracor expression in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648257/how-can-i-get-the-last-match-in-regular-extracor-expression-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
String input ="GUID=1232, awsdqdwe click1 ,GUID=21232 berttt click2, b, GUID=323223,babsjbcjhbcc click3"; 
Pattern click3IdPatttern = Pattern.compile("(?<=GUID[=])\\d+(?=[a-zA-Z ,]+?(click3))");
Matcher matcher = click3IdPatttern.Matcher(input);
String id = matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "";
```

In my regex `"(?<=GUID[=])\\d+(?=[a-zA-Z ,]+?(click3))"` , iam using positive lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: Keep it simple: `GUID=(\\d+),? ?(\\w+) click3`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat , Keeping it simple is one thing. But readability and keeping the regex generic is equally important. We don't need to capture GUID and click3 which is why I'm using lookahead and look behind.

Comment: That is why we use groups. Btw, if you talk about readability, I think the regex that I suggested is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant regular expression would be something like:

```
 GUID=(\d+),.*click3
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Hi, I am using same as suggested, but the value I am getting is  1232. I also ran as per the screenshot you have given, but again m getting 1232.Can you please help

Comment: Most likely you need to add space before GUID